# How to output data in a loop in XML. Android Studio, Kotlin

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

I'm first time working in Android Studio and kotlin and i need output some dynamic data in XML. For example i have some dictionary:

```
{"Tom": '+111111111", "Jack": '+1231231", "Lisa": "34543543534"}
```

And i dont know how i can output this in xml, because data can be any. In JS libraries/frameworks exist some loops for output data, like in React or Vue. Is there something similar in xml?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i recommend to you check out Recycler View topic.

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/recyclerview?gclid=CjwKCAiAvK2bBhB8EiwAZUbP1FimrC6CEG3PoIYl9YtUeaXdJAbhpb3W87GHLfeAByJ8zGi23wKQCBoCIpwQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds